# Android get x y coordinates of tab

Tags: android, tabs, coordinates

In Android tabs, how does one get the x,y coordinates of the currently selected tab? My goal is to automatically scroll to that tab (using scrollTo(x,y)) when it is selected in code.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the x and y location of place where screen has been touched using this

```
 main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
                            {
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
                                 {
                                float x = e.getX();
                                float y = e.getY();
                                return true;                             
                                  }
                        });
```

Hope it helps .